# Calling function on each of numpy array elements and override its value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list:

```
letters = ('1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '13', '21')
```

Having number `8`, I can get it's index in letters as:
`letters.index('8')`

No, I have an array which contains only numbers that are in letters.

```
numbers = [3, 8, 13, 21, 5]
```

How do I call index (or similar) function on each element?

what I want to get is `[2, 4, 5, 6, 3]`

Is there such function as index that can grab array instead on single element?
If that is required letters can be changed to array

Comment: Python terminology nitpick: `letters` is a tuple, not a list. `numbers` is a list, not an array.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
letters = ('1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '13', '21')
numbers = [3, 8, 13, 21, 5]

result = [letters.index(str(n)) for n in numbers]
```

But this works only if all requests are present in `letters`

You can try this to test if the request in `letters`

```
[letters.index(str(n)) if str(n) in letters else -1 for n in numbers]
```

In case request in not `letters`, you will have a `-1`. Beware that `-1` is here to indicate that request is not present. `letters[-1]` returns the last element of the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `map` functions - this is a great problem to apply a new technique.

```
def get_index(letters, element):
    return letters.index(str(element))

indices_of_numbers = list(map(get_index, numbers))
```

we could wrap this in a function so we can remove the `letters` argument from `get_index`.

```
def get_indices_of_numbers(letters, numbers):
    def get_index(element):
        return letters.index(str(element))

    indices_of_numbers = list(map(get_index, numbers))
    return indices_of_numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `letters` to int array and then use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
np.asarray(letters,dtype=int).searchsorted(numbers)
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: letters = ('1', '2', '3', '5', '8', '13', '21')

In [43]: numbers = [3, 8, 13, 21, 5]

In [44]: np.asarray(letters,dtype=int).searchsorted(numbers)
Out[44]: array([2, 4, 5, 6, 3])
```

If `letters` is such that the int array version is not sorted, we need to feed in the additional argument `sorter` with `searchsorted`.